# Newline not working with lists in embedded messages - Discord.py

Tags: list, newline, discord.py

I have a list with newlines as variable called `result`

```
['**Status: **Enabled\n**Q: **What is 2 + 2?\n **\\ A: **4\n\n**Author: **UltimateDucc#9121\n\n\n', '**Status: **Enabled\n**Q: **Where is Ethiopia?\n **\\ A: **Africa\n\n**Author: **BigSnacc#2466\n\n\n']
```

When I send it as an embedded message through discord:

```
            l_msg = discord.Embed(
            title =  f'Page {list_msg}',
            description = str(result), 
            colour = discord.Colour.blue()
            )            
            await message.channel.send(embed = l_msg)
```

It comes out as this with every `\n` being ignored for whatever reason.

[image: embeddedmessage]

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to convert the individual list entries into strings as opposed to just a string representation of the entire list. This is done with [str.join()](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.join).

Try changing the description line to:

```py
description=''.join(result),
```

Result:

[image]