# Py ignoring Newlines

Tags: python, python-3.x, discord, discord.py

Basically the python is ignoring the \n inside the string.

Basically i am calling an api with request.get, and then receiving a response which contains \n inside of it, but whenever i use the response from web that contains \n it ignores it and instead just displays it

I am doing this for a discord bot

Code:

```
@bot.command()
async def genlist(ctx):
        if "BOT ACCESS" in [r.name for r in ctx.message.author.roles]:
            response = json.loads(requests.get(url + f"/api.php?action=orderlist&key=").text)

            if response["status"] == 200:
                orders= str(response["orders"])
                embed=discord.Embed(title="Orders", description="Orders\n" + orders, color=0xcd65f0)
            else:
                embed=discord.Embed(title="Orders", color=0xff0000)
                embed.add_field(name="Unexpected error", value="True", inline=True)
                embed.add_field(name="Message", value= response["message"], inline=True)
                embed.set_footer(text="Error")
```

If anyone knows why, please lmk.

Comment: This might solve your problem: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61569212/newline-not-working-with-lists-in-embedded-messages-discord-py, if `response["orders"]` is a list.

Answer (score 0):

Discord ignores multiple `\n` so to get a dual new line you would have to do `\n\n\u200b` which inserts 2 new lines and space. You could use the [BeautifulSoup](https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/) library to help parse the response.

You could try iterate through the `\n` and add the unicode `\u200b` after it.